# load user control to page dynamically using javascript click event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I've an aspx page which contains information of students. On click of each student (student name is under div tag), I want to load a user control in pop up. the user control will have Fee details of a selected student. I've few actions available in user control say, some search criteria and a button to save it.

Could you please help me to achieve this stuff.
( I can use only this terminology, cannot be changed)

Please let me know if you need more clarity on question.

Comment: You need to post minimal code describing your problem and what are you upto!

Comment: Yes, we can help, provided that you include the code of your current attempt that contains the issue you're having and describe that issue clearly.